# Not about programming, but issues with SublimeText UI

Tags: themes, sublimetext3

Does anyone know (a) why this is happening and (b) better still, how I can fix it.

When I right-click a folder in the sidebar and select "New File" the dialog that shows the textbook to enter a new file name is partially hidden behind the status bar.

I have tried toggling off the status bar, but then the new file dialog just shifts down even lower.

[image: SublimeText New File]

Comment: Have you tried dragging to resize it?

Comment: @sergioFC put that as an answer and I'll accept it. The resize bar is pretty far above the input box so I didn't see it initially and the cursor is pretty dark so I may have missed it. Nonetheless, I tried it again as you said, it it worked. Thanks!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Something similar happened to other user some time ago :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply **resize vertically the panel by dragging it**.

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot! Can't believe that caught me out.